# What customizations are possible for plot.CLD on an emmeans output?

Tags: r, plot, lme4, emmeans

I am trying to figure out how to customize the plot produced by the `plot.CLD` function on the output of `emmeans`. The plot function produces a nice default plot, but it does not seem to share the customization options of `plot.cld`. Also, I cannot find any documentation of `plot.CLD`, only `plot.cld`. I specifically want to add the compact letter display as data labels on the plot. I would also like to switch the xvar and yvar variables to rotate the plot.

I am running a `lmer` mixed effect model on some weight data. I want to compute and plot the compact letter display of the tukey-adjusted `emmeans` output. The function cld was designed for `glht`-type data, which can be visualized using `plot.cld`. The `cld` function was brought forward in the `emmeans` package as `CLD`.

The `plot.CLD` function is active, but was not documented in the `emmeans` package. The customization of `plot.cld` has been documented, but no similar documentation of `plot.CLD` is available. I tried `plot.cld` on my `emmeans` object, but it was not compatible. The only features I have been able to modify is the `xlab=` and `ylab=`. Strangely, `plot.CLD` requires the package `multcompView` but there is no documentation about the function.

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(multcomp)
library(multcompView)
#Generating means
attach(dataX)
x = lmer(plant_kg_cum2~ (genotype) + (1|rep) )
emmeans(x, list(pairwise~genotype), adjust="tukey", ddf="Satterthwaite", level = 0.95)->emmeans1

#producing compact letter display
cld(emmeans1, sort=FALSE, Letters=c("ABCDEFGHIJKL",LETTERS, letters), which=1) ->CLD1

#plot the compact letter display
plot(CLD1, xlab="kg", ylab="Genotype")
```

I even tried adding a title using `main="title"`, but even that was not successful. I tried switching xvar and yvar in my dataframe to re-orient the plot by changing the columns order or using the `x=` and `y=` commands. All gave errors saying it produced NAs.

Comment: CLD produces a summary.emmGrid object, which is an extension of data.frame. There is no CLD class, and obviously, no plot method for a class that doesn’t even exist. Therefore, there is no way to customize such a plot. I guess if you want this kind of plot, you can create a glht object and use whatever plot method is offered by the multcomp package.

Comment: I will add that providing a CLD function is the thing I most regret ever providing in lsmeans/emmeans. It implements an ill-advised approach to significance testing, and promotes a misinterpretation whereby means whose comparisons have P values greater than .05 are depicted as equal. In the light of recent ASA statements making even stronger recommendations regarding routinized statistical testing, my plan is to deprecate CLD in future updates. I am considering alternative ways of depicting pairwise comparisons.